# How we can convert client side rendering react js app to server side rendering using react router 4?

Tags: reactjs, seo, server-side-rendering

How we can convert client-side rendering react js app to server-side rendering using react-router 4?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using Create React App with React Router 4, you'll need to do the following steps:

- Create an SSR server: Add a `root/server/index.jsx` that contains your Express server, serving the default setup of CRA as documented here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#other-solutions
- Render your app on server: Import your `src/App.jsx` component in your `server/index.jsx`, use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App/>)` to render your app to a string, then inject it into the `build/index.html`, and res.send the injected HTML to the browser upon a request.
- Try to run your server: `node server/index.jsx` does not work because node does not understand JSX. You'll need to setup webpack with babel to transpile your `server/index.jsx`, and then run the transpiled file with node. Because your server code imports `src/App.jsx`, which may also import `css, svg, png, jpg, etc.` files, you'll get a lot of errors running your server. Fix errors one by one by configuring your webpack to suit your use cases.
- Hydrate your app on client: After successfully running your server, try to send a request from a browser. You may see a blank page but don't worry because we have not rendered correctly on the server yet. However, let's assume that your server did render something on step 2 above. Then, when your browser receives the HTML page, it just needs to make interactive components like buttons work properly. To do this, edit file `src/index.js` to use ReactDOM.hydrate() instead of ReactDOM.render().
- Render route-based content correctly on server-side: Keep using BrowserRouter in `src/index.js`, but in `server/index.js` on server-side, use StaticRouter instead and pass req.originalUrl to that StaticRouter. This is because BrowserRouter read address from your browser address bar, but the server does not have an address bar.
- Getting correct data on server: server-side does not execute componentDidMount, comonentDidUpdate, and useEffect hook. Only render() function will be executed. Therefore, create hooks to query your data on server-side.

Recommendations if you want to add SSR for CRA:

- Follow this guide: https://medium.com/bucharestjs/upgrading-a-create-react-app-project-to-a-ssr-code-splitting-setup-9da57df2040a
- If you don't understand anything in that guide, learn from this course: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMhLdUN2ZKJ2f-QDFBP1iphsmPd81MQOO